# Remote desktop started to report a certificate error

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, certificate

I connected to some Windows 10 machine with a static IP address via RDP from another Windows 10 machine for some time period probably about couple month. At some moment RDP started to report a certificate error:

[image]

1) What can cause this?

2) Where can I found the previous certificate to check if it expired or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is somewhat normal, as Windows systems always create a self-signed TLS certificate for Remote Desktop (unless they're on Active Directory with AD CS available, in which case they *might* use the domain's internal CA).

While it is possible to install a globally-trusted certificate, practically nobody does that, so on standalone systems you will *nearly always* see the "Not a trusted CA" warning, and you will end up ticking the box to remember this individual certificate instead.

Windows 10 systems also tend to regenerate their Remote Desktop certificate **even if it *hasn't* expired yet** – it most likely happens during full OS upgrade, i.e. the old certificate is probably discarded whenever a new Windows release is being installed.

---

You cannot view the previous certificate on your client, as it only remembers the SHA-1 fingerprint, not the complete certificate. Most likely you cannot view the old certificate on the server either, as the change is often *caused by* the old certificate having been discarded.

However, you can view the *current* certificate on the server by running `certlm.msc` (on the physical screen, of course, not via RDP) and compare its fingerprint to what's being shown by your RDP client.